# svn server and client setup on local machine

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I want to setup Subversion server and client on my local machine and for that I installed VisualSVN Server on my local machine and then I created an account and a group under that and it was configured successfully. Then I imported files to my local machine and take checkout files on same machine using TortoiseSVN and it was working fine. Now I want to checkout my repository files on another machine, I tried it by ipv4 address but it was not working.

Any Help ?

Comment: What was not working? Provide some details.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access VisualSVN Server remotely, you don't need to perform any special steps other than those required to be able to access any server over HTTP(S). In most cases, with properly configured LAN and DNS, VisualSVN Server should be accessible by the URL `https://hostname/svn/` or `https://IP-ADDRESS/svn/`.

Therefore, when you can't connect to VisualSVN Server remotely you should check the most basic things first:

- The machine where VisualSVN Server is installed is remotely accessible from the other machine,
- VisualSVN Server listens on the correct IP interface and port,
- Firewall allows inbound connections on port VisualSVN Server listens to.